# TypeError: Net.createConnection is not a function`

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to connect to a MySQL database using React and Node, and I created a database class to act as a singleton to get the connection to the database, but then it gives me the following error:

`TypeError: Net.createConnection is not a function`

I've done some searching and the main search results I can see are that the code is rendering client side, which doesn't completely make sense to me, considering I'm running this on node js through npm start.

```
    let con = null;
    class Database
    {

    }
    Database.prototype.connection = function()
    {
        if(con!=null) {
            return con;
        }
        var mysql = require('mysql');
        var con = mysql.createConnection({
            host: "localhost",
            user: "yourusername",
            password: "yourpassword"
        });

        con.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
            console.log("Connected!");
        });
        return con;
    }
    export default Database;
```

I apologize if I don't know the correct terminology.

[Error I see in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDvtJ.png)

Comment: Where are you getting the error?

Comment: It's actually a bit more clear with the image -- I haven't posted here before, so I was only able to add a link to the image.

Comment: I'm actually seeing my database 'password' from the browser side in the source code, so perhaps I *am* running the MySQL code from the browser?

Comment: The MySQL library that you are using works with node.js and not in the browser

Comment: I'm not trying to run it in the browser, so I'm unsure why it is. I'm still looking into the issue that I'm having, however, I'm used to PHP, where code is generally run on the server.